# Who wins in battle between "don't mock 3rd party" and "ensure close() called"?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have this block of code I want to unit test:

```
@staticmethod
def _read_from_zip(pkg_zip_path):
    """
    Return a |BlobCollection| instance loaded from *pkg_zip_path*.
    """
    blobs = BlobCollection()
    zipf = ZipFile(pkg_zip_path)
    for name in zipf.namelist():
        blobs[name] = zipf.read(name)
    zipf.close()
    root_uri = os.path.splitext(pkg_zip_path)[0]
    return PhysPkg(blobs, root_uri)
```

It calls ZipFile, a library/third-party package, so I want to write a test that integrates with ZipFile rather than mocking it out (don't mock 3rd-party code rule).

Here's the test I have so far. `initializer_mock()` is a helper function that patches the `__init__()` method on a class, `PhysPkg` in this case:

```
from opcdiag.phys_pkg import PhysPkg

MINI_PKG_PATH = 'test_files/mini_pkg.zip'

@pytest.fixture
def init(self, request):
    return initializer_mock(PhysPkg, request)

def it_can_construct_from_a_zip_package(self, init):
    PhysPkg._read_from_zip(MINI_PKG_PATH)
    expected_blobs = {'uri_1': b'blob_1\n', 'uri_2': b'blob_2\n'}
    init.assert_called_once_with(expected_blobs, ROOT_URI)
```

The problem is, because I don't mock ZipFile, I don't see how I can test that the `close()` method gets called.

Maybe I should write two tests? This one to ensure proper integration with ZipFile by testing results and another with mocking ZipFile to ensure `close()` gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should write 2 tests.  Or you can create a proxy to your library that forwards every method, but counting the number of times that `close` has been called.

I used the word `proxy` instead of `mock` for a reason.  You are not replacing it (as mock objects usually do).  You are just adding a transparent layer.

The reason why you "don't mock 3rd party libraries" is that you need to test them (especially when you update them or could want to update them).  One alternative is to trust the provider.  Another is to create a complete test.  And a third one (yes, the one promoted by "don't mock 3rd party libraries") is to test them only in those aspects that your software effectively uses them.  A `proxy mock` doesn't change this.

Comment: Oooh, awesome! I realize now what I need to do. In the Python mock library there is this notion of "[partial mocking](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/examples.html#partial-mocking)" that equates to the notion of _proxy mock_ you mention. I'd seen it before while reading the documentation but never tried it and didn't think of it for this until you mentioned. That will do the trick beautifully here I'm sure, and can all be in one test :) Thanks!

Comment: @scanny  Glad to ring a bell. :-)